# Is there a port mvc-mini-profiler for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profiling, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm a big fan of the [MiniProfiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) created by Jarrod Dixon and the Stack Overflow team for ASP.NET. Is there a port of it for Rails applications?

Since the core of the profiler is in [JavaScript](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/UI/Includes.js), [JQuery.tmpl](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/UI/Includes.tmpl) and [Less](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/UI/Includes.less) it seems that porting the back-end to Rails would be fairly straight forward, the front-end is already done.

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

The front end architecture allows for POST and AJAX request profiling by attaching profiling ids to every request in a custom header (`X-MiniProfiler-Ids`).

There is a [similar port](http://bjk5.com/post/6944602865/google-app-engine-mini-profiler) for Python and GAE.

Even though [Rack Bug](https://github.com/timocratic/rack-bug) is fairly interesting, the UI is not as rich - POST and AJAX support is not there, there is no API for profiling blocks and use in production is not recommended.

Similarly, NewRelic in [dev mode](https://support.newrelic.com/help/kb/ruby/developer-mode) is not supported in production and does not have the famous MiniProfiler "chicklet" rendered on each page.

Is there a port of MiniProfiler in Rails?

Comment: Kevin, FYI I re-wrote your question a bit and added a bounty

Comment: @SamSaffron today I've asked the same question (almost), I think it could be merged with this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352635/is-there-any-debug-toolbar-for-rails-3-x

Answer (score 20):

Funny that you ask that, turns out we have been busy porting it to Ruby.

See:

- https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-mini-profiler
- The website http://miniprofiler.com and
- The github https://github.com/SamSaffron/MiniProfiler/tree/master/Ruby

Answer (score 11):

#### Have you looked at [Rails-Footnotes](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes)?

"It displays footnotes in your application for easy debugging, such as sessions, request parameters, cookies, filter chain, routes, queries, etc.

Even more, it contains links to open files directly in your editor including your backtrace lines."

Answer (score 4):

There's NewRelic's "Developer Mode".

https://support.newrelic.com/help/kb/ruby/developer-mode

It's not a 1:1 but it does log actions, queries and even show you the source that executed queries.

They also have the source available at: https://github.com/newrelic/rpm

Comment: I guess, but the issue is that it is not something you would run in prd, and you get no "chicklet", really hoping this gets ported, I feel blind when using my rails projects without it.

Comment: There were a few back in Rails 2 days, don't think they've been maintained though.

Comment: Maybe you could mention names of those?

Answer (score 2):

[Rackbug](https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug) is a Rack application, adds a diagnostics toolbar to Rack apps, it looks  similar with  MiniProfiler.

[image]

Take a look at features list:

- Password-based security
- IP-based security
- Rack::Bug instrumentation/reporting is broken up into panels.

  - Panels in default configuration:

    - Rails Info
    - Timer
    - Request Variables
    - SQL
    - Active Record
    - Cache
    - Templates
    - Log
    - Memory
  - Other bundled panels:

    - Redis
    - Sphinx
  - The API for adding your own panels is simple and powerful

It can work on every environment you specified with restriction by IP address

Comment: you mentioned "the UI is not as rich - POST and AJAX support is not there". It's true, I have never ever see debug tools with modern UI and Ajax queries