# Is there any debug toolbar for Rails 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, rack

I used [Rack::Bug](https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug) more than one year ago, now I'd like to use it with a new Rails 3.1 project. I tried to install it, both the master and rails3 branches, but with no luck.

Also tried [some github forks](https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug/network) but they did not work either.

Is there any alternative with the same features?

P.S. I already know newrelic and its [developer mode](https://support.newrelic.com/help/kb/ruby/developer-mode), just looking for something else, more similar to Rack::Bug

Here is a little screen shoot of what is capable of (the green toolbar with debugging informations)

[image: rack bub]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rack bug seems to e fixed, rails3 branch works for me on 3.1.1

Comment: Yes, I've just tried it again and this time it seems to work. However it still has some bugs. I tried the [rails3 branch](https://github.com/brynary/rack-bug/tree/rails3) with this line in my Gemfile `gem 'rack-bug', :require => 'rack/bug', :git => 'git://github.com/brynary/rack-bug.git', :branch => 'rails3'`

Answer (score 3):

Just found [rails-footnotes](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes)

[image]

### Pro:

- Easy to add
- Embed TextMate links in your html to quick edit a file
- Has a trace link near SQL queries that says WHERE the query is executed

### Cons:

- Bad layout, you need to scroll to the bottom of the page, I prefer a toolbar like Rack::Bug
- Cannot be toggled, always executed
- Missing `ActiveRecord` instantiation informations. Very useful when looking for memory leaks.
- Query trace function always include queries like `SHOW FIELDS FROM table SCHEMA` and `SHOW TABLES`
- Lot of useless informations in the assigns tab such as the whole `@_response_body` and the `@_view_renderer` object (which include **a lot** of informations)

Still looking for else, any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out mini profiler, it's the same one used on StackExchange (except ported to Ruby). http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler?view=asciicast