# What is the best way to profile PostgreSQL requests in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, profiling

I would like to show a number of PostgreSQL requests made (and each individual request info) at the bottom of every page when my Rails app runs in development mode. Is there a ready solution for this?

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352635/is-there-any-debug-toolbar-for-rails-3-x

Answer (score 3):

There is a new solution that was covered at railscasts.com, it's the MiniProfiler.

About the gem -> http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/07/12/miniprofiler-ruby-edition

The screencast -> http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler