# ruby on rails profiler returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profiler

I have installed `ruby-prof` and `test-unit` as i am planning to `use` a `ruby profiler` to `profile` my `website` during `development`...

The problem is that when i type `rails profiler` into the console i get nothing...

shouldn't i get some times my app took to load etc.. like `codeigniter`?

or maybe is there any similar `profiler` to `codeigniter` for `rails`?

Comment: are you outputting the Debug info as Debug in an environment set to only log INFO output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, yes, there is real alternatives [RailsMetric](https://github.com/engineyard/rails_metrics), or [Metrical](http://iain.nl/easier-metricfu-with-metrical), which one I prefer. You might want to [know more about this last one reading/watching corresponding RailsCasts by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/episodes/252-metrics-metrics-metrics?language=en&view=asciicast).

Yesterday, [Sam Saffron](http://samsaffron.com/) announced the first released of MiniProfiler for Ruby according to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823712/is-there-a-port-mvc-mini-profiler-for-rails). I think this might respond better to your needs. For more informations, read [the article on his blog](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/07/12/miniprofiler-ruby-edition).